# android how to add separator/divider in submenu

Tags: android, android-menu, divider

In theory simple thing, but I'm not able to find response.

How to add separator/divider (horizontal line) between submenu items in action bar (in xml).

I expected that using `group` will change something but unfortunately no.

Min sdk 14, target 18.

Comment: add `textView` with `1dp high` with black background

Comment: Guys, please read well. "Between submenus". It means I have xml called menu with structure <menu ...> <item ...> <menu...> <item...> ... </item></menu></item></menu>. How to add the separator/divider here.

Comment: seriously there's no way? :S

Comment: @rupps, Until now I haven't found any way to do this....

Comment: @user2707175 neither did I.. I ended up nesting submenus, but is uglier :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a view like:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="2dip"
android:background="#FF00FF00"
```

Look here: [horizontal rule](http://sonnygill.net/android/horizontal-rule/)

Comment: Guys, please read well. "Between submenus". It means I have xml called menu with structure <menu ...> <item ...> <menu...> <item...> ... </item></menu></item></menu>. How to add the separator/divider here.

Comment: Hi Did u get any workaround for this.I am scratching my head from last 2 days on this problem